# How to validate specific input fields in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to validate all fields within a div but I only want to validate specific fields. [Here is a jsfiddle to show what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/k92Pc/7/)  Once validation is passed the div is hidden. I have to enter data in all of the fields so if you check 'Yes' from the checkbox you will see a input field appear I don't want to include that and also if you select 'NoGame' from the dropdownlist once you enter data in all the fields apart from the two fields in the lower div (green border) and click the Test1 button you will see what I mean. Any suggestions?

This is the code which validates all fields and then Hides the div, which can also be seen in the fiddle

```
  function IsValid(divid) {
var $div = $('#' + divid);
var result = true;
$.each($div.find("input[type='text']"), function (i, input) {
    if ($(input).val().length == 0 || $.trim($(input).val()) == '') {
        result = false;
        return;
    }
});

return result;
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#hide").click(function(){
                if (IsValid('contentone')) {
$('#contentone').hide();
 };
             });
         });
```

Comment: I did this and i didn't see anything. Can you explain what you want to do in simple words..? like, i want to avoid following elements from validation, something like that..?

Comment: If you go onto the fiddle and enter data in all fields(including the hidden fields which you can find by selecting 'NoGame' from the dropdownlist and Selecting 'Yes' for the checked box and click the test1 button you should see the div disappear. Basically I want to validate only certain fields within the div so for example I want to validate field id=ddd but not field id=reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input fields of type text that you don't want to validate exclude them from the validation process

```
function IsValid(divid) {
var $div = $('#' + divid);
var result = true;
var excludeElement = ["reason"]; //<-- EXCLUDED ELEMENTS IDS
$.each($div.find("input[type='text']"), function (i, input) {
    if ($.inArray($(input).attr('id'), excludeElement) < 0 && ($(input).val().length == 0 || $.trim($(input).val()) == '')) {
        result = false;
        return;
    }
});

return result;
}
```

Comment: That seems to work but only for 1 of the elements can I not add more?

Comment: yes it is array . . .`var excludeElement = ["reason", "element2"]` use as many elements as you want to exclude

Comment: can you also show me how to include a validation summary I would want it to be displayed at the top of the page